# Plot different entries of a table with different colors in Mathematica

Tags: plot, colors, wolfram-mathematica

In Mathematica, I have a table in which each entry of the table is a curve in 3 dimensions. I want to assign different colors to different curves, but I don't know how to do it.

My current command is:

```
Plot3D[
      Table[
            Max[Table[SocPlanGen[4,1,1,R,2,p,Min[4/(1+2 k/N),N], N], {k,0,N}]]
                ,{N, 1, 4}
           ]
      , {R,2,20}, {p, 0.1, 1}
      , PlotStyle -> ColorData[1, "ColorList"], PlotLegends -> {"4","3","2","1"}
      ]
```

where SocPlanGen[.] is a function I have defined earlier.

The outer Table[.] has 4 entries ({N,1,4}). Each entry of the outer Table[.] is a curve defined in the space (R,p), and I want each curve to be of a separate color. But the way I currently have it, all curves are the same color because they belong to the same Table.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: You might have better luck posting this on: [http://mathematica.stackexchange.com](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com). Ask for the question to be moved there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [ColorFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorFunction.html) option?

The best example similar to your problem (and corresponding solution) involving Tables, seems to be implemented here (using ColorFunction and another method by the user **belisarius**):

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16963/how-do-i-identify-each-surface-in-a-multi-surface-plot3d

Answer (score 0):

graphics functions have a HoldAll attributes, meaning that the set of parameters are determind on the basis of the unevaluated form of the first argument. Since its head is Table (rather than List) is allocates a single color.
To change the default behavior just enclose the first argument of the Plot3D in Evaluate[]

Since the definition of SocPlanGen is not provided, I cannot check it myself, but I'm quite certain that this is the solution